# Sometime duplicate message receive and send suddenly in a socket

Tags: java, android, kotlin, socket.io

I'm having problems with a simple java socket client: the connection is established properly and both server and client receive and send data. But some time message receiving and sending 2 or 4 times. I have used following library https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

initialisation of socket in `Application` class

```
public static Socket getSocket() {

    if (mSocket == null) {
        try {
            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            String[] opt1 = new String[1];
            opt1[0] = "websocket";
            opts.transports = opt1;
            //opts.reconnection = true;

            //opts.reconnection = false;


                mSocket = IO.socket(BuildConfig.SOCKETURL);


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.i("SOCKET", "info>>" + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return mSocket;
}
```

Code of receiving event in `Activity` class

```
socket?.on("newMessage", object : Emitter.Listener {
        override fun call(vararg args: Any?) {
           // logic after call back goes here
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Problem is 'newMessage' event is triggered  multiple times sometimes, in `onDestroy()` event is `socket?.off("newMessage")` unregistered.

Comment: Is socket server running in system or Android ?

Comment: Can you show your example code ?

Comment: @Googlian socket server is running on AWS EC2 instance without load balancer

Comment: Can you find which method is duplicating ?

Comment: @Googlian socket?.on("newMessage", object : Emitter.Listener {})

Comment: not sure where in code the problem is but I can tell you the problem which is that you have multiple listeners which listening to the same event. maybe you're not unsubscribing to the event listener when user changes a chat and simply adds another binding to the same event.